# Use of Ninject and an injectable DataLayer in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make an MVC3 application with an exchangeable data layer. I currently have this in a single file (Global.asax.cs) for brievity.

It seems to be working as I want but as I'm new to DI I really would appreciate comments on this code.

```
public interface IDataLayer
{
    dynamic GetItem(int id);
    dynamic SaveItem(dynamic item);
}

public class MockDataLayer : IDataLayer
{
    public dynamic GetItem(int id)
    {
        dynamic item = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        item.Id = id;
        item.Name = "Some name";
        return item;
    }
    public dynamic SaveItem(dynamic item)
    {
        return item;
    }
}
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Display(int id = 0)
    {
        dynamic viewModel = Global.DataContext.GetItem(id);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{        
    public static IDataLayer dataContext;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IDataLayer>().To<MockDataLayer>();
        dataContext = kernel.Get<IDataLayer>();

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("", "{id}", new { controller = "Main", action = "Display", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tip I would give is to use the ["Ninject for ASP NET MVC 3"](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.MVC3) NuGet package. Install that package into your project. After doing this, you should find a file named "NinjectMVC3.cs" located in the "App_Start" folder. In this file, look for a method named `RegisterServices()`:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IDataLayer>().To<MockDataLayer>().InRequestScope();
}
```

This sets up a `MockDataLayer` to be returned for each separate web request. This ensures that `MockDataLayer` is disposed when the web request is completed. Now, when you want to create an instance of the data layer, use MVC's built-in [`DependencyResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) class:

```
var dataContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataLayer>();
```